# Inserting the variables of a function into an array and get the max value

Tags: arrays, swift, function

I have a problem with swift strings and arrays. In a function I would like to define 3 numbers (say x, y and z) and then form an array with those variables, and want to return the max() number in the array. However, I am getting an error with the type. (It is asking me to wrap to type etc.
I am posting the code below. can anyone look at it please:

```swift
    func AAA(x: Int, y: Int, z:Int) -> Int {
        let BBB: [Int] = [x, y, z]
        var greatest: Int? = BBB.max()
        return greatest
    }
```

I am getting an error with the "greatest" variable because of its Int? type, but when I convert Int? to Int then I can not call the max value of the array BBB.

Comment: FYI there's already a function for taking the max of 3 (or more) variables [`max(_:_:_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541407-max)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return is a non optional `-> Int`  and you return `greatest` which is  `Int?` , so You need

```
  func AAA(x: Int, y: Int, z:Int) -> Int {
      return [x, y, z].max()!
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, yours is very clean. I saw that I have used extra and unnecessary array. and also in your solution, I saw that if I make max()! in mine, it is also working. Thank you again.